# How to create and write into text file in Lisp

Tags: file, file-io, lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I want to know, how to create and write text file in lisp.
I just want to write simple line like:

```
"break 1"
"break 2"
```

I am using LispWorks IDE on Window 7

Comment: You can refer to [the Cookbook](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
(with-open-file (str "/.../filename.txt"
                     :direction :output
                     :if-exists :supersede
                     :if-does-not-exist :create)
  (format str "write anything ~%"))
```

You may also choose different settings for the `with-open-file` macro. If you use `:append` instead of `:supersede` then you can write into the text file while preserving its context instead of superseding the available content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I am able to create and write into the file, but i cannot able to append into the file. I have change :if-exists to :append but no help, it is display the error "file already exist". You may suggest something...

Thank You for help

Comment: you are supposed to use :if-exists :append not just :append if I understood it right. You can also check this : http://psg.com/~dlamkins/sl/chapter19.html    
It describes other options like overwrite, etc.

Comment: What's the '/.../' for? Does that mean './filename.txt', or just 'filename.txt'

Comment: @claytontstanley , the first one. you can write into a file in any directory in your machine. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @YBE; no problem; just wanting a bit of clarification on the post; thanks