# Importing a lisp data structure into python

Tags: python, pandas, lisp

**Quick Aside** So, I'm a bit of a rookie with Python; therefore forgive my incorrect ways of describing things AND ask me questions if I don't provide enough information.

Ask my title indicates, I'm attempting to bring in a data set that is Lisp data structure. I'm trying to start small and work with a smaller data set (as I'm going to be dealing with much larger eventually) however, I'm unclear as to *how I should set up my separators for my pandas*

So, I'm bringing in a .dat file from a lisp data structure, and reading it with pandas (or attempting to).
My goal, is to try and have it be a normal data set, where I can separate a given, say function, with its' respected outputs.

My Lisp Data set looks like the following:

```
(setf nameoffile?'
((function-1 output1) (function-2 output2 output3 output4) (function-3 output5 output 6 output7...)
(function-4 output)
...
(function-N outputN outputM ... )) )
```

Hopefully this is not too cryptic. Please, let me know if I'm not providing enough information. 
Lastly, my goal is to have all of the functions, lets say in a row and have the outputs read *across* the row in a pandas dataframe (since I'm used to that); for example:

```
function-1: output1
function-2: output2 and so on and so forth...
```

Again, please let me know if I'm a bit confusing, or did not provide enough information. 
Thank you so much in advance!

**EDIT:
My specific question is how can I insert this somewhat ambiguous lisp data structure into a pandas dataframe? Additionally, I dont know how to modify what I want into their desired rows and on *how* to separate them (delimiter/sep = ?). When I insert this via pandas, I get a very mumble jumbled dataframe. I think a key issue is how do I separate them appropriately?**

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Your question is unclear. However, since you, _apparently_, want to load **data** into **pandas**, the answer is, _probably_, [CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response!
I added an edit with a more "specific" question. Hopefully that helps. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: It's probably easier to make a small Lisp program that writes the data in a suitable format than it is to write Lisp parser (even if you only need to handle a few special cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Lisp program isn't already too large, consider rewriting it in [Hy](https://hy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Hy is a Lisp dialect, so you can continue writing in Lisp. But also,

> Hy maintains, over everything else, 100% compatibility in both directions with Python itself.

This means you can use Python libraries when writing Hy, and you can write a module in Hy to use in Python.

I don't know how your project is setup (and I don't know Pandas), but perhaps you can use this to communicate directly with Pandas?

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @molbdnilo and @sds, it's probably easier to export data from lisp in a common format and then import them in Python using an existing parser.

For example you can save them to [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file from Lisp, using the [cl-csv](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/cl-csv) library that is also [available on quicklisp](http://quickdocs.org/cl-csv/).

As you can see from [cl-csv tests](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/cl-csv/blob/master/tests/csv.lisp#L88), you can get a csv string from you data using the [`write-csv` function](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/cl-csv/blob/master/csv.lisp#L158):

```
(write-csv *your-data-rows* :always-quote t)
```

Or, if you want to proceed line-by-line, you can use `write-csv-row` function.

Then will be easy to save the resulting [string into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495376/how-to-create-and-write-into-text-file-in-lisp) and read this [CSV from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+csv?sort=frequent&pageSize=30).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the clarification and instruction! I'll be giving it a whirl in just a bit!