# How to create and write into text file in Lisp (continued)

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9495670/12407473

From the question above, when I try to work the code I get

> "Error: no function definition: STR".

Can anyone tell me why it does not work for me?? Thank you!

```
(with-open-file (str "/.../filename.txt"
                     :direction :output
                     :if-exists :supersede
                     :if-does-not-exist :create)
  (format str "write anything ~%"))
```

Comment: `with-open-file` is Common Lisp, not AutoLisp.

Comment: [file handling functions in AutoLisp](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP-Reference/files/GUID-F70DECFC-DBE1-4F04-A64C-B3F869A636A2-htm.html)

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://www.jefferypsanders.com/autolispintr_rw.html

Comment: I found both those by googling "autolisp write file"

Comment: Thanks! I guess my problem was I was googling "LSIP create text file". That and I'm dumb!! ;D

Comment: You need to remember that AutoCad uses their own, proprietary Lisp dialect. Generic Lisp answers won't always work.

Comment: And, so, onto the why. Since AutoLISP has no `with-open-file` macro, it treats that expression as a function call. Which means that the syntax `(str ..)` looks like an argument expression to produce the first argument of the nonexistent `with-open-file` function. AutoLISP is evidently evaluating the arguments of a function before looking it up that function itself, so it discovers first that a function named `str` doesn't exist.   A more mature Lisp dialect can produce static warnings about all undefined functions and variables in the expression before evaluating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by others in the comments, the example code that you are using is Common LISP, not AutoLISP (the dialect of LISP used by AutoCAD). As such, functions such as `str`, `with-open-file`, and `format` are not defined in the AutoLISP dialect.

In AutoLISP, the general approach would be as follows:

```
(if (setq des (open "C:\\YourFolder\\YourFile.txt" "w"))
    (progn
        (write-line "Your text string" des)
        (close des)
    )
)
```

Commented, that is:

```
;; If the following expression returns a non-nil value
(if
    ;; Assign the result of the following expression to the symbol 'des'
    (setq des
        ;; Attempt to acquire a file descriptor for a file with the supplied
        ;; filepath. The open mode argument of "w" will automatically create
        ;; a new file if it doesn't exist, and will replace an existing file
        ;; if it does exist. If a file cannot be created or opened for writing,
        ;; open will return nil.
        (open "C:\\YourFolder\\YourFile.txt" "w")
    ) ;; end setq

    ;; Here, 'progn' merely evaluates the following set of expressions and
    ;; returns the result of the last evaluated expression. This enables
    ;; us to pass a set of expressions as a single 'then' argument to the
    ;; if function.
    (progn

        ;; Write the string "Your text string" to the file
        ;; The write-line function will automatically append a new-line
        ;; to the end of the string.
        (write-line "Your text string" des)

        ;; Close the file descriptor
        (close des)
    ) ;; end progn

    ;; Else the file could not be opened for writing

) ;; end if
```

Comment: Great thank you for all the descriptions!! How on earth does it know where to save the text file after opening from thin air though?? 
I have (open "xref_list.txt" "w"), and when i close it, no matter what dwg i have open it always finds its way back to the same folder. what if i want it saved relevant to the dwg i have open?

Comment: If you do not specify the full path name of the file, `open` assumes you are referring to the AutoCAD default drawing directory (which is typically the My Documents folder on fresh installations). If you want to create the file in a specific location, simply supply the full filepath - for example, to create the file in the work directory, you might use `(open (strcat (getvar 'dwgprefix) "xref_list.txt") "w")`